# Execute two different queries as a single mysql query

Tags: mysqli

```
$query1 = "SELECT 
    SUM(dischargecount) AS dis, MONTHNAME(dischargedate) AS n
FROM
    user
WHERE
    DATE(dischargedate) BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
GROUP BY MONTH(dischargedate)";


$query2 = "SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT response_user) AS val1,
    MONTHNAME(response_on) AS m
FROM
    response
WHERE
    response_on BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
GROUP BY MONTH(response_on)";
```

I want to execute the two queries as one.

Comment: What do you mean by execute as one? Do you wish to perform a `JOIN`? On which field? How are your tables laid out?

Comment: i dont have any common fields in the  tables

Answer (score 0):

Select col_name $q1,col_name $q2 from $query1 $q1,$query2 $q2 where condition1 AND condition2;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(dischargecount) AS dis, MONTHNAME(dischargedate) AS n
FROM
    user
WHERE
    DATE(dischargedate) BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
GROUP BY MONTH(dischargedate)
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT response_user) AS val1,
    MONTHNAME(response_on) AS m
FROM
    response
WHERE
    response_on BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
GROUP BY MONTH(response_on)
```